Automatically run PowerShell script as administrator
I'm trying to create a script to add/modify some registry keys. To test it I'm modifying simple keys from the power modes on my laptop. However I'm struggling to create a ps1 file that opens with admin rights to be able to change registry.
I've tried using the runas command, but it only opens a new PowerShell prompt that doesn't have elevated permissions. I've also found this link that shows how to add through registry the option to run ps1 files as administrator, however it didn't work for me.
Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?
The script I'm using to test is very simple and it works when using an elevated terminal:
powercfg /setactive ab6534a3-bc02-4c44-94d1-a8535b2eb070

set-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Samsung\SamsungSettings\ModulePerformance" -name "value" -value "2"


When you run these commands in a PowerShell prompt are the changes sucessfully applied? You talk about struggling but don't really explain, what the problem is exactly, i assume you are having problems running the script automatically. Is there a reason this script has to be ran more than once?  The power configuration mode you are changing shouldn't change that often.

@Ramhound My goal is to to create a ps1 file that i could just double click and run the script as admin. I've also tried changing the execution policy from restricted to remotesigned  and unrestricted, but no luck. i'm using the power configuration just as a test, the real application is going to be different. To this test i created a script that sets the power mode to high performance, and another one that sets it back to normal mode.

@DrMoishePippik I've tried creating a .bat file with the same script, and also pointing to open the .ps1 file. Both didn't work. For .bat files i get the option to run as admnistrator, but on .ps1 files i only get "run with powershell" (Win11). I found a topic showing how to create this option for ps1 files adding some registry keys, but it didn't work as well.

@Ramhound forgot to say, but it does work properly when using an elevated powershell terminal.

Put this code in your ps1
$ArgumentList = @'

powercfg /setactive ab6534a3-bc02-4c44-94d1-a8535b2eb070

set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Samsung\SamsungSettings\ModulePerformance' -name 'value' -value 2

'@

Start-Process -FilePath powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $ArgumentList


It did work! Thanks! Just out of curtiosity, why is it necessary to add the ArgumentList?

@AugustoBarbosa Don't understand your question, the ArgumentList is the commands you want PowerShell should do.
